# MySQL FTS works on test server but not live

Tags: mysql, apache, full-text-search

I'm wondering what could possibly cause this? I am stumped as I have been searching for an answer for 2 days now.

I have a big table, around 390.000~ rows. So there's no problem with the 50% treshhold. I have been building this site on my test server using XAMPP. I have now moved everything to my server using Ubuntu. Website files + mysql tables.

I have also set the only two settings I can think of in my my.cnf, min_word_length and ft_stopword_file. On the test server I get perfect results from my searches. On my live server I get barely any results (although some, sometimes).

I am just wondering what settings I could've forgotten to get my live server to work?

I know this is a fuzzy question but I think it could be useful for many people in the same situation in the future.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are the indexes populated on the live server? I don't know MySQL, but I know in SQL Server you can have the change tracking set up so it automatically populates the FTS indexes or you can have it set to update on a schedule or have it be a manual process.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I have created FTS indexes for the things I'm searching, and updated my tables.

Comment: Can you run a population of the index manually?

Comment: I don't know how to do this sorry, I'm quite a beginner I suppose.